# Submit PHP form to MYSQL database using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a `PHP` page that displays records from a `MYSQL` database in a table. I want to be able to edit the record in the table cell by clicking on the cell. The process I picture would go like this:

1) `onclick()` event on table cell triggers `ajaxfunction()`
2) `ajaxfunction()` sends cell data to php page which querys the database and displays drop down list of options.
3) user selects option from drop down list
4) `onchange()` event submits form to database
5) table cell or page is refreshed to show the current table cell data. (not currently in my existing code)

Right now I've got two `PHP` pages `ac_sched.php` and `ModSched.php`.

Here is the structure of each page:

`ac_sched.php`:

- `PHP` created table displaying `MYSQL` records
- `ajaxfunction` to query the database for available cell options

`ModSched.php`:

- `PHP` code to select the available cell options from the database and create dropdown.
- `PHP` code to update the database with the selected option from the dropdown.

Here are the relevant sections of code from each page:

```
ac_sched.php:

<script>
function ACSchedQuery(reg)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById(reg).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../process/ModSched.php?ModSched_Reg="+reg,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<table>

<tr>
<td id="ABC-Day-3" onclick="ACSchedQuery(this.id)"></td>
</tr>

......rest of table here......
</table>


ModSched.php:

// This is to request the options from the database  
if(isset($_GET['ModSched_Reg']))
    {
    $ModSched_Array = explode("-",$_GET["ModSched_Reg"]);
    $ModSched_Reg = $ModSched_Array[0];
    $ModSched_Day = $ModSched_Array[1];
    $ModSched_ID = $ModSched_Array[2];

    $sql4 = ("SELECT * FROM aircraft_sched_options WHERE SchedOpt_ID != 0");

    if(!$result_sql4 = $mysqli->query($sql4))
        {
        echo QueryCheck("getting the schedule options ","from the aircraft sched options",$mysqli);
        }
    ?>
    <form action="../process/ModSched.php" method="post">// I did try: action=""
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

        <tr>
        <td>
    <?php
    echo "<select name=\"ModSched_ID\">";

    while($SchedOpt = $result_sql4->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $ModSched_Reg . "-" . $ModSched_Day .  "-" . $SchedOpt['SchedOpt_ID'] . "\" onchange=\"formSubmit(this.form)\"";
        if($SchedOpt['SchedOpt_ID'] == $ModSched_ID)
            {
            echo " selected=\"selected\"";
            }
        echo ">" . $SchedOpt['SchedOpt_Name'] . "</option>";
        }

    echo "</select>";
    ?>
        </td>
        </tr>

        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
    }  

// This is to submit the selected option to the database
if(isset($_POST['ModSched_ID']))
    {
    $ModSched_Array = explode("-",$_POST["ModSched_ID"]);
    $ModSched_Reg = $ModSched_Array[0];
    $ModSched_Day = $ModSched_Array[1];
    $ModSched_ID = $ModSched_Array[1];

    $sql4 = ("UPDATE aircraft_status SET $ModSched_Day = $ModSched_ID WHERE AC_Reg = $ModSched_Reg");

    if(!$result_sql4 = $mysqli->query($sql4))
        {
        echo QueryCheck("updating the aircraft schedule ","into the aircraft sched",$mysqli);
        }

    }
```

I know that is a lot of code, but I think it's all needed in order to show the whole story.
I think if someone just takes a look at the code structure that I have, that will tell me if I'm on the right track or not, that would be a big help. Here are the questions I have regarding my code:

1) Is the form to submit the changes in the right place?
 - I previously had a second `ajaxfunction()` to submit the selected option to the form submit page. This didn't work, but it could have been my code and not the structure itself.

2) Should I have the form submit code on its own page?

I have just started to use `AJAX` this week, so I could be way off the mark here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using a library like jqGrid or DrasticTools?

Comment: You should for sure look into jquery

Comment: @Barmar no, I've never heard of those.

Comment: @Barmar it looks like jqGrid does something like I'm trying to do. Have you used it for a similar application?

Comment: Yes, I have. I've also used DrasticGrid, but it doesn't have as many features.

Comment: Very cool, I'm going to check it out. I'm also in the middle of exploring cakephp as suggested by @user1036004

Answer (score 0):

You can implement some framework like [cakephp](http://cakephp.org/) or [symphony](http://symfony.com/legacy), this framework can help you in the process to learn this language and good practices.

Comment: I've heard a little about these frameworks but I have never used them. Would they help me with situations like this? Maybe it's time to take the plunge.